# Как задать псевдоним типа "указатель на функцию"?

Tags: c++

Как задать псевдоним типа `указатель на функцию` с помощью `typedef`?

Comment: по-моему так: typedef  rettype (*name)(argtype arg1,...);

Comment: @nick_n_a имена аргументов не нужны.

Comment: @alexolut, но их присутствие же не является ошибкой?

Comment: @Grundy нет. Но я не знаю ситуаций, когда их можно было бы использовать. Вы знаете?

Comment: @alexolut, возможно какая-нибудь IDE может их подсказывать как-нибудь, в качестве варианта применения :)

Comment: @Grundy кстати, да. Студия подсвечивает.

Answer (score 0):

Примерно так, с нужным числом аргументов и типом результата

```
typedef bool (*t_func)(int,int);

bool isEqual(int x, int y) {
  return x == y;
}

t_func my_func = &isEqual;
```

вызывать: (*my_func)(7, 3);

Comment: Разыменование при вызове не является обязательным. И возвращаемые типы у Вас не совпадают.

Comment: Я думаю настоящим ответом является страничка из help-а по синтаксизу typedef. это так, сжатый ответ.